# How to measure space between lines of text drawn on screen?

Tags: winapi, fonts, draw, measure

We have an end-user application that allows you to write multiple lines of text into a text box, it persists this information to a text file.  Upon the next session that information is retrieved from the file to display the text.  The problem is sometimes on the next session the bounds of the text box are cutting of the text so the user is having to manually resize the textbox.  I'd like to programmatically figure out if the text box needs to be resized.

GetTextExtentPoint32() seems to work well for measuring the actual drawn width of the line based on the current font selected into the Device Context.  However now I'm tackling the need to resize the textbox bounds in the vertical direction.  GetTextExtentPoint32() does give me the height, which seems correct, but the total height I get is a bit too small.  I believe I need to measure the space between each line, but I'm not quite sure?

Update: It looks like I'm looking for TEXTMETRIC.tmExternalLeading and TEXTMETRIC.tmInternalLeading.  What's interesting is for some fonts and sizes, the calculation is spot on and I can fit my text perfectly.  But for some fonts and sizes, the calculation is a bit too small, in that case it seems the leading is too small or 0?

Comment: Search for the end-goal: Compute the height of text in a text box.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I remember you can use [GetTextMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and (Metrics.tmAscent + Metrics.tmDescent) should be the value you're looking for

Comment: The height returned by GetTextExtentPoint32() appears to be equivalent to Metrics.tmAscent+Metrics.tmDescent.  The problem is that I need to know the measure of the space between the lines of text.  So the cumulative height I calculate is correct only if there's 0 space between the lines of my text. It appears the leading will tell me but Metrics.ExternalLeading=0 and the internal leading is too small.